# Preview PDF and Text File Before uploading using Jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

I have a project in which I have to preview file before uploading. I don't know about JS. Can you guide me how to preview a PDF file before uploading?

Comment: Please provide more information. We can assume that you are using an asp.net MVC app, but we don't know what kind of libraries you are using. Have you attempted anything as of yet? Most likely you are going to wind up using some sort of third party library to do this, but it is against Stack Overflow policy to have questions asking for suggestions about which third party tool to use.

Comment: Hello! bro first i upload a file on server in preview folder and then preview it  but i need to if there any method or library that help me to preview file without uploading it to server.